# File descriptors redirecting is stuck

Tags: python, sys

In the daemon class example, which I implement, is used descriptors redirecting.

```
sys.stdout.flush()                       
sys.stderr.flush()                       
si = file(self.stdin, 'r')               
so = file(self.stdout, 'a+')             
se = file(self.stderr, 'a+', 0)          
os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno()) 
os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno()) # This line doesn't work
os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
```

`os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())` is not working. It doesn't raise errors. The code after this line is not executed.

I simplified this example to the class contains only the problem area:

```
class Deamon(object):
    def __init__(self, pidfile, stdout='/dev/null'):
        self.pidfile = pidfile
        self.stdout = stdout
    def get_stdout(self):
        so = file(self.stdout, 'a+')
        os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
        print 'executed'
```

After `os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())` code just stuck.
Why is it happening?

**Edit** (with @C2H5OH code implementation):

```
    try:                                                           
        pid = os.fork()                                            
        if pid > 0:                                                
            # exit first parent                                    
            sys.exit(0)                                            
    except OSError, e:                                             
        sys.stderr.write(                                          
                'fork #1 failed: %d (%s)\n' % (e.errno, e.stderror)
                )                                                  
        sys.exit(1)                                                

    os.chdir("/")                                                  
    os.setsid()                                                    
    os.umask(0)                                                    


    try:                                                           
        pid = os.fork()                                            
        if pid > 0:                                                
            # exit from second parent                              
            sys.exit(0)                                            
    except OSError, e:                                             
        sys.stderr.write(                                          
                "fork #2 failled: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strrerror)
                )                                                  
        sys.exit(1)                                                

    # redirect standart file descriptors                           
    os.setsid()                                                    
    sys.stdin.flush()                                              
    sys.stdout.flush()                                             
    sys.stderr.flush()                                             

    dev_null = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)                      
    os.dup2(dev_null, sys.stdin.fileno())                          
    print 'executed 1'                                             
    os.dup2(dev_null, sys.stdout.fileno())                         
    print 'executed 2'                                             
    os.dup2(dev_null, sys.stderr.fileno())                         
    os.close(dev_null)    

    # write pidfile
    # FIXME: file is not writes!                     
    atexit.register(self.delpid)                
    pid = str(os.getpid())                      
    file(self.pidfile, 'w+').write("%s\n" % pid)
```

In the `stop` method I have try-out of `self.pidfile` existing:

```
def stop(self):                  
    print file(self.pidfile, 'r')
```

This is raise an error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/deamon-example.pid'

The problem is still in there.

Comment: By the way, Python documentation [recommends to use `open()` instead of `file()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing Python file handles with the operating system file descriptors, this is asking for trouble.

While you are correct on using `os.dup2()` to redirect `sys.stdout` (because direct assignment may not completely work, if other modules acquired a reference to it), you should open files at the operating system level with `os.open()`.

Here's the daemonization code we use at my workplace:

```
if os.fork() > 0:
    os._exit(0)
os.setsid()
sys.stdin.flush()
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stderr.flush()
null = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)
os.dup2(null, sys.stdin.fileno())
os.dup2(null, sys.stdout.fileno())
os.dup2(null, sys.stderr.fileno())
os.close(null)
```

If you want to redirect stdout to some file, just use a different file name instead of the predefined constant `os.devnull`.

Comment: I try to implement your suggestion. The problem is not resolved now. Is it after the first use dup2, dev_null closes? Is it the problem? I added to my post implementation some of your code to the main daemon class. Help me to resolve and understand please.

Comment: After re-reading your question, what exactly do you understand for _getting stuck_?  How do you know the execution doesn't go beyond the first `dup2()`?  Keep in mind that once you redirect your standard output to `/dev/null`, you won't see anything `print`-ed.  In order to trace the execution, you should be logging to a file.

Comment: Once again, I changed my question. After the problematic line code is not executes, the pidfile is not writes, see above in the question. Thank a lot!

Comment: I'm not deeply understand it yet, but I got it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.dup2

Above documentation says: `os.dup2(fd, fd2) Duplicate file descriptor fd to fd2, closing the latter first if necessary.`

So this line:
`os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())`
is apparently closing `sys.stdout` which effectively shuts down all output. The code appears 'stuck', but you're just not seeing any output. i.e., there are no errors.

On top of that, you're redirecting stdout to `/dev/null` anyway:

```
def __init__(self, pidfile, stdout='/dev/null'):
    #...
    self.stdout = stdout         # <--self.stdout points to /dev/null
def get_stdout(self):
    so = file(self.stdout, 'a+') # <-- opening /dev/null for append?
    # even if the next line worked, you're appending to /dev/null and you wouldn't see any output
    os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
```

Comment: I try to implement @C2H5OH 's advice and consider your advice too. `tmp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
os.dup2(tmp.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())                         
os.dup2(tmp.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
os.dup2(tmp.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())`
>So this line: os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno()) is apparently closing sys.stdout. How to change this behavior?

Comment: @I159: I don't know how to change that behavior. You should probably be paying more attention to C2H5OH's answer. It sounds like he has more experience and better insight. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks alan!  I was using print statements to trace through a daemonized program, and they stopped after the line os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno()).  I wrote directly to a log file after that and could see the program was continuing to run after all!